# add variable to array in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, loops, extendscript

using extend script to push a variable into an array it's basically javascript. any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
if ( app.documents.length > 0 ) {

    for ( i = 0; i< app.activeDocument.textFrames.length; i++) {
         var allSizes = []; //set up empty array

        textArtRange = app.activeDocument.textFrames[i].textRange;
        var fontName =  textFonts.getByName("Nobile");
        alert (fontName);
        textArtRange.characterAttributes.textFont = fontName;
        var fontSizes = textArtRange.characterAttributes.size;

        allSizes.push(fontSizes)
        alert (fontSizes);

    }
        alert (allSizes);
}
```

the alerts for allSizes only return single values, not the array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Move the definition of `allSizes = []` outside the loop.

Currently, you're "resetting" the value of `allSizes` at each loop.

Answer (score 9):

You're setting up the empty array inside of the for loop. It's resetting it each time. Move it above the for loop:

```
var allSizes = []; //set up empty array
for ( i = 0; i< app.activeDocument.textFrames.length; i++) {
     .....
```

Comment: wow, that was totally it. what a noob move, ha! can't believe i didn't see that. thanks!

Comment: @Lukasz: You need to accept an answer to this question. Do it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer that helped you most.
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work